# how can I set a dot / bar on specific section of a line plot in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, charts, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I've started playing with pyqtgraph plotting line charts.

I have the need to draw specific dots in some section of the lines.

I found that in order for dots to appear on the line,
I need to use symbolBrush when plotting E.g

```
curve3 = p1.plot(pen=(2,5) , name="trade" , symbolBrush=2)
```

But the thing is it shows dots on the entire line,

and I can't seem to find a way to draw a dot for specific points / sections.

Assistance would be appreciated

Edit:
For example, In the attached image, assume I only want to draw a dot where marked (1,1) without dots being drawn on the other line breaks.

[image]

Comment: What are those specific positions? Could you show an image of what you want to obtain?

Comment: Assume X axis is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and y axis is [2,4,2,4,2,4,2,5,2] I want a "clean line" and a highlighted dot (E.g. brush = 2) on value 5 in the y axis

Comment: Do you want to show a point in the coordinates (0, 5)?

Comment: Yes I guess so, what I am looking for was some ability to dynamically set the brush on and off per value of the Y axis array

Comment: explain yourself better, and an image would be very useful pointing out what you want.

Comment: see attached image for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163508/discussion-between-y-s-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Have you considered adding additional scatterPlotItems to your plot that contain only the coordinates where you want the dots?

Comment: hi @three_pineapples, not familiar with it, can you kindly share an example?

Answer (score 0):

So, here is an example of what you are looking for. It's a bit "dodgy" in that I'm accessing something inside a `PlotDataItem` that probably shouldn't be directly accessed, so there is a risk that this code may become non-functional with future updates to pyqtgraph.

That said, I think the risk is reasonably low, it would be easy to update my example to work with whatever changes are made to pyqtgraph, and the example may spark an idea in you that leads to a path that achieves the same thing, without needing to abuse the internals of pyqtgraph.

```
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
x = np.arange(8)
y = [1,6,2,4,3,5,6,8]
p = pw.plot(x=x, y=y, symbolSize=25)
p.scatter.setData(x=[x[2]],y=[y[2]])
pw.show()
```